# How to add new rows (loop) in a table without overwritting

Tags: matlab

I'm extremely new to Matlab. Sorry if it's a simple question..

I'm trying to write a loop to add new rows.

```
    files = dir('*.mat');
     for ii=1:numel(files)
                file = files(ii);

             Variable = str;
             Correlation = RCDvsMOVRAW;
             Signification = pRCDvsMOVRAW;
             Lag = lagDiff;

    T = table(Correlation,Signification,Lag,'RowNames',Variable);
end
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If you have a table already, you can add rows by concatenation: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-and-delete-table-rows.html  The `T= table(...)` should not be in your loop, you can either convert your matrix into a table first (and then add rows) or add rows to your matrix first and then convert it to a Table, in either case, you should move this line out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
    files = dir('*.mat');

   for K=1:numel(files)
     file = files(K);
       mat = load(file.name);

         Variable = {mat.str};
         Correlation = mat.RCDvsMOVRAW;
         Signification = mat.pRCDvsMOVRAW;
         Lag = mat.lagDiff;

         T2(K,:) = table(Variable,Correlation,Signification,Lag);

   end

       writetable(T2)
```

Hope this helps